# Trouble Pushing to PFQueryTableViewController after Facebook Login

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, parse-platform

I log in successfully with Facebook. The Login view is a UIViewController. I can only get access to Parses' login feature by using

```
@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController <PFLogInViewControllerDelegate, PFSignUpViewControllerDelegate>
```

The problem is, once I successfully login, I'd like the user to see a PFQueryTableViewController. The app is all based on lists so, it makes sense to push to this.

I tried this:

```
- (void)logInViewController:(PFLogInViewController *)logInController didLogInUser:(PFUser *)user
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{ 
        NSLog(@"Successfully logged in.");
        MyPFQueryTableViewController *controller = [[MyPFQueryTableViewController alloc] init];

        //Not sure what to do here...


       }];

}
```

Originally I pushed to the TableView. I've since deleted that code and frankly I have no idea how I did it.

But what happened was I see the UIViewController for a brief second, and then the PFQueryTableViewController appears.

Not only that but the PFQueryTableViewController didn't show a navigation bar, even though the table is embedded in a navigation controller.

Here's the code for my LoginViewController.m

```
#import "LoginViewController.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import "MyPFQueryTableViewController.h"

@interface LoginViewController ()

@end

@implementation LoginViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}


 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
 [super viewDidLoad];
     PFLogInViewController *login = [[PFLogInViewController alloc] init];
     login.fields = PFLogInFieldsFacebook;
     // Need to set the delegate to be this controller.
     login.delegate = self;
     login.signUpController.delegate = self; //signUpController is a property on the login view controller
     [self presentModalViewController:login animated:NO];


 // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
 }



/*
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;
    MyPFQueryTableViewController *controller = (MyPFQueryTableViewController *)
    navigationController.topViewController;


}


- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    MyPFQueryTableViewController *controller =
    [[MyPFQueryTableViewController alloc] initWithClassName:@"Lists"];
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:NO completion:nil];

}
*/




//Four delegation methods below.

- (void)logInViewController:(PFLogInViewController *)logInController didLogInUser:(PFUser *)user
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{ 
        NSLog(@"Successfully logged in.");
        MyPFQueryTableViewController *controller = [[MyPFQueryTableViewController alloc] init];

        //Not sure what to do here...
    }];

}
```

I thought maybe I need to use the segue method, but I'm not too sure.

**Update:**

Per below answer I'm trying to push the login via presentModalViewController in the MyPFQueryTableViewController.m file.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    PFLogInViewController *login = [[PFLogInViewController alloc] init];
    login.fields = PFLogInFieldsFacebook;
    login.delegate = self;
    login.signUpController.delegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:login animated:NO];

    //self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}
```

See my below comment for the warning I'm getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to have PFQueryTableViewController as the initial view controller and present the LoginViewController modally when the application starts. This is what I did when I used Parse in one of my apps

Comment: Oh, that actually could work... Would it be too much trouble to see some of that code? If so, no big deal. Hadn't thought of that!

Comment: I don't have my app code on me at the moment but if you're using storyboards set the MyPFQueryTableViewController to be the initial view otherwise in the app delegate's application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: set it as the rootViewController then in MyPFQueryTableViewController's viewDidLoad initialise the loginViewController and present it.

Comment: Sweet. I'll give it a whirl tonight. I'll keep this open until then and should it work out I'll close it out. Doesn't PFLoginViewController only "inherit" from UIViewController? I guess that's why I never thought I could do this.

Comment: I have a warning: "Assigning to 'id<PFLogInViewControllerDelegate> from incompatible type 'MyPFQueryTableViewController'. I'll add my code from the viewDidLoad method above.

Comment: You need to add <PFLogInViewControllerDelegate> to the header file at the end of the "@interface" line.

You'll also need to implement any delegate method's you want to use. You can find them here: https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Protocols/PFLogInViewControllerDelegate.html

Comment: Oh. I thought if I put that in the .h file it was fine. Thanks! That fixed the errors, but it breaks at [super viewDidLoad]; in the query table. Nothing up in my console but, I set a BP for all exceptions and it's highlighting that line.

Comment: Actually I just commented out [super viewDidLoad]; and it ran, but post logging into FB, it crashes.

Comment: Have you implemented the delegate methods for PFLogInViewController in MyPFQueryTableViewControler? 

You'll need to implement these 3:
– logInViewController:didLogInUser:
– logInViewController:didFailToLogInWithError:
– logInViewControllerDidCancelLogIn:

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25258/discussion-between-stangmmx-and-dos43)