# Login on Parse framework with swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I'm trying Parse and Swift. 
I would like to hide login view after login success.

I used dismissViewControllerAnimated in method `logInViewController(logInController: PFLogInViewController!, didLogInUser user: PFUser!)`, but It does not work for showing up next viewController.

OS: MacOSX 10.9.4
Xcode: 6.1 beta2

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController,
                      PFLogInViewControllerDelegate,
                      PFSignUpViewControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        //Create Login 
        var loginViewController:PFLogInViewController = PFLogInViewController()
        loginViewController.fields = PFLogInFieldsDefault
        presentViewController(loginViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        loginViewController.delegate = self
        loginViewController.signUpController.delegate = self
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func logInViewController(logInController: PFLogInViewController!,
                           didLogInUser user: PFUser!)
    {
        logInController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        //var nextViewController:RegisterViewController = RegisterViewController()
        //presentViewController(nextViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

How can I hide loginViewController and show up next ViewController?

Comment: Have you tried self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil) instead?

Comment: self.dissmissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:nil) does not work. LoginViewController still show up.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trouble Pushing to PFQueryTableViewController after Facebook Login](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102770/trouble-pushing-to-pfquerytableviewcontroller-after-facebook-login)

Comment: The linked answer 'PFQueryTableViewController as the initial view controller and present the LoginViewController modally when the application starts' I recognized is that LoginViewController I made as main should implement PFQueryTableViewController, instead of UIViewController? The result is that building is successful, but it shows next error.

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "vXZ-lx-hvc-view-kh9-bI-dsS" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
func logInViewController(logInController: PFLogInViewController!,
                       didLogInUser user: PFUser!)
{
    var nextViewController = RegisterViewController()
    self.presentViewController(nextViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question. What you do is dismiss the current VC, then in the completion block you present the NextViewController.

```
func logInViewController(logInController: PFLogInViewController!, didLogInUser user: PFUser!) 

    logInController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: { () -> Void in
        var nextVC = NextViewController()
        self.presentViewController(nextVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    })

}
```